# Java ByteBuffer for Zipfile

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I have a binary file that contains big endian data. I am using this code to read it in

```
FileChannel fileInputChannel = new FileInputStream(fileInput).getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb  = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int)fileInputChannel.size());
while (bb.remaining() > 0)
    fileInputChannel.read(bb);
fileInputChannel.close();
bb.flip();
```

I have to do something identical for zip files. In other words decompress the file from a zip file and order it. I understand I can read it in via ZipInputStream but then I have to provide the coding  for the "endianness". With ByteBuffer you can use ByteOrder.

Is there an NIO alternative for zip files ?

Comment: Data in a zip file are compressed format, so changing order in byte is meaningless. As you write in your question, unzip first, and swap in byte to make change their endians.

Comment: You don't need any of this. Use the `ZipInputStream` provided in the JDK. You're starting from the wrong place, and you certainly don't have to deal with endian issues in a ZIP file.

Comment: @EJP- The endian issues are NOT in the ZIP file. They are in the uncompressed file. Sorry if the text does not convey the question accurately enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your `ZipInputStream`, just use [`Channels.newChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel(java.io.InputStream)) to convert it to a `Channel` then proceed as you wish. But you should keep in mind that it might be possible that a `ZipInputStream` can’t predict its uncompressed size so you might have to guess the appropriate buffer size and possibly re-allocate a bigger buffer when needed. And, since the underlying API uses byte arrays, there is no benefit in using *direct* `ByteBuffer`s in the case of `ZipInputStream`, i.e. I recommend using `ByteBuffer.allocate` instead of `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` for this use case.

By the way you can replace `while(bb.remaining() > 0)` with `while(bb.hasRemaining())`. And since Java 7 you can use [`FileChannel.open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) to open a `FileChannel` without the detour via `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Of all the people who answered only you understood my question ! And thanks for the code review as well !!